# Call a function with unknown type and number of parameters in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I am writing a library in C# and I have to call some methods defined by other programmers in their classes, so I do not priory know about types and number of parameters. For example,

```
Class exampleClass{
    void method1(int param1, double param2){...}
    bool method2(){...}
    object method3(string param1){....}
}
```

In my program, I want to call these methods. As I don't know their parameters and return types, I cannot use "*delegate*"s (which have known types and parameters) but in run-time, I can use, for example, reflection to extract methods and their parameters ("*MethodInfo*"s) from the class but how to use this information to call the methods? (assuming that I can generate the proper values to be used as the parameters of methods).

Thanks

PS: I know "params object []" approach but it will force programmers to use "params" objects instead of defining their usual parameters in their methods. So, I don't want to use this approach.

Comment: What arguments would you pass for the parameters anyway? If you could give more information about the context, that would make life a lot easier.

Comment: Please tell more about the context. How would you or people use it if they don't know the signature of the method? It looks as if it would be too easy to make a mistake and pass incorrect variable. If you have access to the classes why you are not able to extract definitions?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: you can assume that I will give the default value for each parameter or assume that parameters are within a limited known set and for each of that types I have a procedure to create a value of that type.

Comment: @oleksii: in run time and using reflection, I can obtain the signature of each method as a "MethodInfo" which, among all, has information about name and type of method and also type of each parameter.
In fact, I am writing a simulator program  and a person who uses my program will write a class with some methods (and defines some attributes for each method) and in run-time, I compile the code and obtain the information about each method and then, call some of those methods.

Answer (score 7):

You can use reflection to get all the information you need about a method.

For example once you have the [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ff1et9k.aspx) you can get the [`ReturnType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx)

```
Type MyType = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.FieldInfo");
MethodInfo Mymethodinfo = MyType.GetMethod("GetValue");

Console.Write ("\n" + MyType.FullName + "." + Mymethodinfo.Name);
Console.Write ("\nReturnType = {0}", Mymethodinfo.ReturnType);
```

[`GetParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) will tell you the parameters:

```
Type delegateType = typeof(MainClass).GetEvent("ev").EventHandlerType;
MethodInfo invoke = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
ParameterInfo[] pars = invoke.GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo p in pars) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.ParameterType);
}
```

Once you have this information you can use [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) to actually call the method.

Its first argument is the "object on which to invoke the method".

Its second argument is the argument list for said method.

Comment: yes, but the problem is how to call these methods with the information obtained from the reflection

Answer (score 1):

The code I'm providing works with the ExampleClass you provided, but in no way is it a complete solution. You need to take generics, ref, out params, and probably a whole lot of other things into consideration.

```
public void CallAllMethods(object instance)
{
    foreach (MethodInfo method in instance.GetType().GetMethods())
    {
        if (method.IsGenericMethod || method.DeclaringType == typeof(object))
        {
            // skipping, System.Object method or a generic method
            continue;
        }

        var defaultParamValues = method.GetParameters().Select(p => GetDefaultValue(p.ParameterType)).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking {0} with param values {1}", method.Name, string.Join(", ", defaultParamValues));
        object retVal = method.Invoke(instance, defaultParamValues);

        if (method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  and returned a value of {0}", retVal);
        }
    }
}

public static object GetDefaultValue(Type type)
{
    return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
}
```